# Understanding multi-contact relay connection diagram

Tags: relay

Can someone explain this relay pin drawing to me? It is a [Releco C5-A30](http://www.releco-relais.net/en/Relays-MRC/C5-A3x.pdf). Why are the contacts labeled twice, bold and not? Can someone explain how they'd wire this for just a simple N/O switch?

[image: screenshot of photo of relay and the relay connection diagram from the datasheet]

Comment: What do you intend  supply to coil AC or DC? and contacts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a simple NO switch, it's a three pole dual throw relay switch.

As to the double numbering, the not bold numbers are European standard terminal markings where first digit is the pole, second is a contact codes  1 = common, 2 = NC and 4 = NO. The BOLD numbers are everybody else.

[image]

If you look at the socket for it, you will see the same markings.

[image]

If you WANT to wire it as a simple single pole NO relay, hook up your coil voltage across A & B, and use either pin pairs 4 & 7, 5 & 8 or 6 & 9 as your switch.

Comment: The bold numbers is the pin labeling in the socket to the relay, see "Dimensions [mm]" in the datasheet.

Comment: That's "three pole, double throw".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast each pole is a single connection, 3 poles means there are 3 switched being controlled together. Dual throw means a switch with a normally open and normally closed contact.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - conceivably usage has changed, but I'm pretty sure the it's "double", not "dual". The adjective for one is single, the adjective for 2 is double, and for 3 it's triple. for instance, if you google SPDT, you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDT and there are almost no links to "single pole dual throw".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast interesting, it was always dual in my neck of the woods, but the meaning is the same I guess.